# Existing answers repel answerers from bounties

Tags: discussion, bounties

I believe I see couple of patterns regarding questions with bounties:

a) In the case if a question has multiple answers, people tend to skip this question

I believe the thinking is following "Taking into account that the question has multiple answers, there is less chance of winning a bounty, so doesn't make too much sense to spend time on it"

What makes situation even worse, if you put a bounty on the question which had already several answers (which weren't correct).

b) In the case, if first answer is long, people tend to skip this question either.

Quite similar explanation. Long answer assume the knowledge of answerer (which mean less chance for next person to win a bounty).

My question is: Does it make sense to introduce some mechanism to encourage people to look at bounty questions with answers.

The main reason of this question, because I hate to see people spending their reputation to bring more attention to some question and failing to do so, just because there were some answers already or first answerer wrong long (and incorrect) answer.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this or is this just a guess?  It certainly isn't the way I treat bounty questions.

Comment: This already exists. You can use a custom message... However, if you think you can improve on an answer don't hesitate to answer it; you can get the bounty out from the noses of the other answerers then.

Answer (score 5):

That mechanism *is* the bounty mechanism. I personally check the message - there are several options, and only one of them is "reward an existing answer". Apart from that (which actually seems to be pretty rare), bounties do their job of encouraging people to look at the question.